# Cant find reference to codebuild source custom command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am building a cloudformation script for codepipeline and am stuck at codebuild stage.

This is how my CodeBuild script looks like

```
CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: Dev-Build
      ServiceRole: !Ref ServiceRoleForCodepipeline
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/standard:3.0
        EnvironmentVariables:
          - Name: stage
            Type: PLAINTEXT
            Value: dev
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: buildspec.yml
```

This works fine. My doubt is how do I setup `Source` item to accept custom command instead of a `BuildSpec` file here

```
Source:
  Type: CODEPIPELINE
  BuildSpec: buildspec.yml
```

In the console here we can specify custom commands.
[image]

I have gone through the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codebuild-project-source.html) the Source reference doesnt say anything about adding custom commands. Any help is appreciated. Stuck on this for sometime now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BuildSpec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codebuild-project-source.html#cfn-codebuild-project-source-buildspec) is used for that:

> if this value is provided, it can be either a **single string containing the entire build specification**